# Incoming traffic is not forwarded to correct docker container

Tags: linux, docker, networking, udp, iptables

There is an incoming traffic with port 1111/UDP from Server-A to Server-B and Server-B has multiple containers up and running and one of the containers (udp-listener) is listening on port 1111/udp and it's IP is (172.17.0.2), the issue is:

1. Stop container "udp-listener" with ip **172.17.0.2**
2. Start new container like Nginx, so now Nginx has the ip **172.17.0.2**
3. start "udp-listener" which has the next IP available **172.17.0.3**
4. and now, the incoming traffic from Server-A is still trying to access **172.17.0.2**, here is the output

```
    $ tcpdump port 1111
    17:30:09.875982 IP Server-A-IP.pvsw > 172.17.0.2.pvsw: UDP, length 49
```

and now if I give the "**udp-listener**" container IP `172.17.0.2`, then is going to work again.

Any hint where can I look up, btw Server-A is not accessible and it just set to send event to server-B public IP.

what is the best practice for debugging? is there any tools or any tutorials?

I also checked IP tables for any rules, but I could not find anything, here is the result:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2178 packets, 155K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  12M  805M PREROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  12M  805M PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  12M  805M PREROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3408K  204M DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 780 packets, 46800 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 789 packets, 47332 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
6021K  361M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 807 packets, 48412 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       172.17.0.1           172.17.0.1           udp dpt:8080
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       172.17.0.2           172.17.0.1           udp dpt:1111

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
3348K  201M RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-4a68f517a271 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:8080to:172.17.0.1:8080
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1111 to:172.17.0.2:1111
```

Comment: did you touch iptables manually? last rule it's explicitly forwarding udp traffic on port 1111 to IP 172.17.0.2... it will be good if you provide more information so somebody can replicate the issue, maybe you or somebody should report the issue on https://github.com/moby/moby

Comment: last one is chain Docker, whenever you create container and exposed port it will add new rule to iptables. what kind of information do you need? I really do not know where to look or which kind of information should I provide.If you explicitly forward a port, it will add it to PREROUTING.